# Width of right trapezoid at a given height?

Tags: geometry

I have a right angle trapezoid and would like to find the width $XY$. 
The only known dimensions are $AX, XD, DC$. Angles $A, X$ and $D$ are $90$ degrees.
I wonder if it is possible to do this.
I have added a little sketch.
Thank you for your insight.

[image: Trapezoid sketch]

Comment: The length of $XY$ depends on $\alpha$.

Comment: Imagine $AXD$ and $BYC$ are two sticks. Now you can rotate $BYC$ at point $C$ while still keeping $DC$ fixed, right?

Comment: Both comments above are true.

Comment: Hint: Add a "vertical" line from $B$ to its intersection at $F$ with $DC$. Now $BF=AD$, so $FC$ can be computed from Alpha and $AB=DF=DC-FC$.

Comment: Thank you, but Alpha is not known...

Comment: You can not calculate XY